# Horror novel with demons or monsters living in the walls of a house

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, demons

I read a horror book in the late 80s. The general idea is a house that has demons/monsters living in the walls and are dragging people in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  As you say, there's not a lot of information here.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good story-id questions and [edit] in any other details that you recall.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could this be Graham Masterton's *Walkers* (1989)? It involves violent ghosts dragging people into the walls. See a summary here: [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/363409.Walkers)

Comment: Yes it is....thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

One possibility from the correct timeframe is [*Walkers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11116) (1989) by Graham Masterton.  The cover blurb reads:

> An idyllic retreat? Or a madhouse soaked in blood? Only the Walkers can tell you...
>
> The Oaks is an idyllic, up-market country club – but its ornately carved walls hide a horrific past. Sixty years ago the house was an asylum, home to crazed psychopaths. One night all of them disappeared, never to be seen again.
>
> Jack Reed, the owner of The Oaks, has no idea about the building's terrible history. It is only when Jack's son is dragged into the walls of the mansion that he realizes what happened sixty years ago – and just where the inmates have been living all this time...

The major difference is that the dwellers in the walls are the insane ex-inmates of the asylum, not demons.  As one of the characters says they are not quite human anymore, but they're not obviously monstrous.  (What they *do* on the other hand...)

[image: Cover of "Walkers" showing a person grabbed by hands extruding from a brick wall]

The book is available to borrow (free registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/walkers00mast/).

Comment: Yes that's the book... many thanks